# TikTok Api Issue in node js application

Tags: node.js, api, wrapper, tiktok

I'm using https://github.com/tikstock/tiktok-app-api/ in my node js application and when I try to use one of the features, it says "Could not sign an API URL. This usually means the signature service is not responding." How do I use a different signature service other than the default?